# Could not find member '@odata.type' on object of type 'TeamMemberSettings'

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the example from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) to add a team to existing 365 group.

the line:

```
            await graphClient.Groups[GroupID].Team
            .Request()
            .PutAsync(team);
```

Shows an error that does not make sense to me.

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. Microsoft.Graph.Core: Code: InvalidRequest
>   [10/16/2019 7:49:36 PM] Message: Could not find member '@odata.type' on object of type 'TeamMemberSettings'. Path 'memberSettings['@odata.type']', line 1, position 66.,Could not find member '@odata.type' on object of type 'TeamMessagingSettings'. Path 'messagingSettings['@odata.type']', line 1, position 205.,Could not find member '@odata.type' on object of type 'TeamFunSettings'. Path 'funSettings['@odata.type']', line 1, position 329.,Could not find member '@odata.type' on object of type 'Team'. Path '['@odata.type']', line 1, position 384.

I had this done before in a console application and it worked. 
Does it have anything to do with the fact that it is an Azure function or that it is .NET core 2.2?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that we started setting odata.type on all models. The type is correctly set, it is just that the service isn't ignoring the value as should be expected. This is a service issue that was exposed by a change in the client library. The client workaround is to set the odatatype property to **null** when creating the Teams objects.

```cs
Team newTeam = new Team()
{
    GuestSettings = new TeamGuestSettings
    {
        AllowCreateUpdateChannels = false,
        AllowDeleteChannels = false,
        ODataType = null
    },
    MemberSettings = new TeamMemberSettings
    {
        AllowCreateUpdateChannels = false,
        ODataType = null
    },
    MessagingSettings = new TeamMessagingSettings
    {
        AllowUserEditMessages = true,
        AllowUserDeleteMessages = true,
        ODataType = null
    },
    FunSettings = new TeamFunSettings
    {
        AllowGiphy = true,
        GiphyContentRating = GiphyRatingType.Strict,
        ODataType = null
    },
    ODataType = null
};
```

Comment: "ODataType = null" solved my issues too. Sadly this still seems to be an unfixed bug.

Comment: Code snippets for the graph api explorer are still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Added Microsoft.Data.OData to the project and used older versions

```
 <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.OData" Version="5.8.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" Version="1.0.0-preview.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="1.17.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
```

that seem to make it work. 
I wonder why it was not installed as a dependency.

Comment: you should be using a newer version of the OData library. The library is currently at 7.6.1 and we don't update 5.x version anymore since it is out of the support.

Comment: @Saurabh are your sure? Just checked this and the most recent version nuget is finding is 5.8.4...

Comment: The one for Core is 7.6.1