# Could not find member '@odata.type' on object of type 'Team'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm having trouble adding a Team to a Group previously created with Microsoft Graph.

I am using the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) (1.19.0) to work with Microsoft Graph, following the .NET Core tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-core?tutorial-step=1).

Authentication is made with the client flow (console running as a deamon) and I have no problems building a `graphClient` or authenticating:

```
// Auth info
var tenantId = "xxx";
var clientId = "xxx";
var clientSecret = "xxx";
var scopes = new List<string> { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// Create ConfidentialClientApplication
var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

// Create authenticationProvider
ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes[0]);

// Create graph client
// Use graph BETA endpoint
var baseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/";
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(baseUrl, authenticationProvider);
```

Or creating a group:

```
var groupName = "Team group";
var groupDescription = "Awesome group";
var group = new Group
{
    DisplayName = groupName,
    Description = groupDescription,
    GroupTypes = new List<string> { "Unified" },
    Visibility = "Private",
    MailNickname = groupName.Replace("", string.Empty).ToLower(),
    MailEnabled = false,
    SecurityEnabled = false
};
// Send the POST request to create group 
group = await graphServiceClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(group);
```

But when adding a Team to the new group:

```
var team = new Team();
await graphServiceClient
    .Groups[group.Id]
    .Team
    .Request()
    .PutAsync(team);
```

I get the following error:

```
Code: InvalidRequest
Message: Could not find member '@odata.type' on object of type 'Team'. Path '['@odata.type']', line 1, position 15.
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
request-id: xxx
date: 2019-10-30 09:12:04
ClientRequestId: xxx
```

But when serializing the team-model to JSON the result is:

```
{"@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.team"}
```

Which would suggest that there is an OData Member with a type of Team.

I've tried to add both NuGet packages `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` and `Microsoft.Data.OData` as per this suggestion here: [Could not find member '@odata.type' on object of type 'TeamMemberSettings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420993/could-not-find-member-odata-type-on-object-of-type-teammembersettings), but it didn't work.

I've also tried calling the endpoint directly with an `HttpRequest` which yielded the same result. I also tried using the same code in a .NET Core and .Net Framework app.

Comment: It seems a issue has been added https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can repoint the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) to the Beta version, it will still only use the v1.0 data models. To actually use the Microsoft Graph Beta, you should use the [Microsoft Graph Beta SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/0.8.0-preview).

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Beta -Version 0.8.0-preview
```

You're also using a deprecated endpoint that will be removed before the end of the year. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http):

> This API is in the process of being deprecated in favor of [Create team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta%5C), and will be removed by the end of 2019. For details about how to create a team from a group, see examples 4 and 5 in [Create team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta%5C).

To create a [Team from a Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta#example-4-create-a-team-from-group), you issue a `POST` like this:

```
await graphServiceClient
    .Groups[group.Id]
    .Team
    .Request()
    .PostAsync(team);
```

Also, keep in mind that this note from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta#example-4-create-a-team-from-group):

> If the group was created less than 15 minutes ago, it's possible for the Create team call to fail with a 404 error code due to replication delays. We recommend that you retry the Create team call three times, with a 10 second delay between calls.