# Could not find member 'group@odata.bind' on object of type 'Team'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, beta

I am trying to create a team from Group using a specific template. Below is my API call.

```
                var team = new Team
                {
                    DisplayName = "My Class Team",
                    Description = "My Class Team’s Description",
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('educationClass')"},
                        {"group@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups('89c3399b-3722-438c-b106-55a2c7eccf2a')"}
                    }
                };

                var teamCreated = await graphClient.Teams
                  .Request()
                  .AddAsync(team);
```

But I am getting an error that,

> Could not find member 'group@odata.bind' on object of type 'Team'.
> Path '['group@odata.bind']', line 1, position 202.,Could not find
> member 'template@odata.bind' on object of type 'Team'. Path
> '['template@odata.bind']', line 1, position 306.,Could not find member
> '@odata.type' on object of type 'Team'. Path '['@odata.type']', line
> 1, position 380.,Could not find member 'template@odata.bind' on object
> of type 'Team'. Path '['template@odata.bind']', line 1, position
> 435.,Could not find member 'group@odata.bind' on object of type 'Team'. Path '['group@odata.bind']'

I already checked and applied the fixes mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622650/could-not-find-member-odata-type-on-object-of-type-team) post but still not able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added all required permissions displayed in below image at Application level:

[image]