# Odata.bind error when creating a team with microsoft graph

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using miscrosoft graph with .net core to create a team in Microsoft Teams. But when I send the request for the team creation I always get an error message:

> Invalid bind property name template in request.

To do that, I followed the step required in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#example-4-create-a-team-from-group

I already tried a bunch of example from the Microsoft documentation, from the v1.0 and beta one.

My group creation looks like this:

```
        {
            var email = groupName.ToLower().Replace(" ", "_");
            //Create a new object group
            Group group = new Group
            {
                DisplayName = groupName,
                GroupTypes = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Unified",
                },
                MailEnabled = true,
                MailNickname = email,
                SecurityEnabled = false,
                AdditionalData = additionnalData,
            };
```

with the additionnal data being:

```
           var additionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"members@odata.bind", new List<string>()},
                {"owners@odata.bind", new List<string>()}
            };
            (additionalData["members@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add(TeamsApi.GetUserOData(ownerEmail));
            (additionalData["owners@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add(TeamsApi.GetUserOData(ownerEmail));
```

And my team creation look like this:

```
            Team team = new Team
            {
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"group@odata.bind",$"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups({newGroupId})"},
                    {"template@odata.bind","https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')"},
                },

            };
            return await GraphClient.Groups[newGroupId].Team.Request().PutAsync(team);
```

So here is my question: What am I doing wrong? Is it a syntax error? Where I can find a documentation about Odata.bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420993/could-not-find-member-odata-type-on-object-of-type-teammembersettings)

I put a property `ODataType = null` to every object created.

```
Team team = new Team
{
    ODataType = null,
    Channels = new TeamChannelsCollectionPage(),
};

Channel general = new Channel
{
    DisplayName = "Général",
    ODataType = null
};

team.Channels.Add(general);

return await GraphClient.Groups[newGroupId].Team.Request().PutAsync(team);
```