# Problem with add channel to Microsoft Team (C# code, cast channel type to interface)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

i have a application in Microsoft teams, and i want add channel from Visual Studio (c#).
In the [examples in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#example-3-create-a-team-with-multiple-channels-installed-apps-and-pinned-tabs-using-delegated-permissions), we can see this lines:

```
Channels = (ITeamChannelsCollectionPage)new List<Channel>()
{
    new Channel
    {
        DisplayName = "Class Announcements ",
        IsFavoriteByDefault = true
    },
    new Channel
    {
        DisplayName = "Homework ",
        IsFavoriteByDefault = true
    }
},
```

But if i try do that in Visual Studio i get a InvalidCastExeption

[image: exeption]

my code and Example code are equal

i think the SDK(Microsoft Graph) was updated, but documentation - not

My Microsoft.Graph SDK version - 3.9.0

PS. problem with cast  type "Channel" to interface "ITeamChannelsCollectionPage"

Comment: How can you explicit cast `List<Channel>` into a `ITeamChannelsCollectionPage`?

Comment: @Cleptus As of the mentioned docs example 3 we can. However seems odd to me also.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Was editing the question so it is more readable, just checked the provided link and indeed the MS documentation seems weird.

Comment: The documentation seems to be wrong, that explicit casting cannot be done. In this [related but not duplicated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191591/2265446) they do use a `TeamChannelsCollectionPage` instead a `List<Channel>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the documentation there is completely wrong - you cannot cast like that. The correct way to use the Graph SDK is like this:

```
var team = new Team
{
    Channels = new TeamChannelsCollectionPage
    {
        new Channel
        {
            DisplayName = "Class Announcements"
        },
        new Channel
        {
            DisplayName = "Homework "
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The `IsFavoriteByDefault` property does not exist, it was perhaps valid in an older version of the SDK.