# Unable To Create An Event With Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an [Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example) using [The Microsoft Graph API](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web) in .Net 5 with ASP.
I have been to [The Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and as weird as its sounds, 
sometimes but not always an event wont create using the demo code provided (see below)

```
{
    "subject": "My event 0",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2021-04-09T00:00:36.595Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2021-04-16T00:00:36.595Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

> "error": {
> "code": "RequestBodyRead",
> "message": "The property 'subject' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type. REST APIs for this mailbox are currently in preview. You can find more information about the preview REST APIs at [https://dev.outlook.com/."](https://dev.outlook.com/.%22)
> }
> }

Here is the payload of an [Event object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#methods) I am attempt to create an event with.

```
{
      "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
      "attendees": [
        {
          "type": "required",
          "emailAddress": {
            "address": "andrew@andrew.com",
            "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.emailAddress"
          },
          "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.attendee"
        }
      ],
      "body": {
       "content": "hello,world",
       "contentType": "html",
       "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.itemBody"
       },
      "end": {
      "dateTime": "2021-04-10T11:11:00.0000000",
      "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time",
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.dateTimeTimeZone"
      },
      "isAllDay": false,
      "location": {
        "displayName": "Microsoft Teams Meeting",
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.location"
       },
      "start": {
        "dateTime": "2021-04-10T11:10:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time",
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.dateTimeTimeZone"
      },
      "subject": "Andrew",
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.event"
    }
```

> Status Code: BadRequest
> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: RequestBodyRead
> Message: A type named 'microsoft.graph.event' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type. REST APIs for this mailbox are currently in preview. You can find more information about the preview REST APIs at https://dev.outlook.com/.

It might be worth mentioning that so far all other requests both `Get` & `Post` have been successful when using the SDK/API.

Scopes used

```
        public readonly static string[] Scopes =
        {
            "User.Read",
            "MailboxSettings.Read",
            "Calendars.ReadWrite",
        };
```

Code Used To Send The Request.

```
        var timeZone = User.FindFirst("graph_timezone").Value;

        var @event = new Event()
        {
            Subject = teamsMeetingRequest.Title,
            Attendees = attendees,
            IsAllDay = teamsMeetingRequest.IsAllDay,
            Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = teamsMeetingRequest.StartDate.ToString("o"),
                TimeZone = timeZone
            },
            End = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = teamsMeetingRequest.EndDate.ToString("o"),
                TimeZone = timeZone
            },
            Body = new ItemBody()
            {
                Content = teamsMeetingRequest.Body,
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            },
            Location = new Location()
            {
                DisplayName = "Microsoft Teams Meeting"
            },
            AllowNewTimeProposals = true
        };

        await this._graphClient.Me.Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
```

**Update** StackTrace 
 All other error's in both The Graph Explorer And Response From The SDK/API Are Mentioned Above.

```
Status Code: BadRequest Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException:
Code: RequestBodyRead
Message: A type named 'microsoft.graph.event' could not be resolved 
  by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve 
  to a valid type. REST APIs for this mailbox are currently in preview. 
  You can find more information about the preview REST APIs at https://dev.outlook.com/.
Inner error:    
AdditionalData:     
date: 2021-04-10T02:46:11   
request-id: removed for question    
client-request-id: removed for question 
ClientRequestId: removed for question
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at TeamsMeetingCreator.Controllers.ValuesController.CreateTeamsMeeting(TeamsMeetingRequest teamsMeetingRequest) in Path To My File.
```

**Update**
I have tried POSTMAN to send the request with the above payloads so there shouldnt be any `ODataType` issues but unfortunately the same error exists.

> "The property 'subject' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event'

**Update**
I have tried creating an Event with no properties and it has successfully created, I then tried to Update the event

```
// Update The Event.
@event = await this._graphClient.Me.Events[emptyEvent.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(@event);
```

However the same error is returned

> The property 'attendees' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event

Comment: Please post the complete `exception.ToString()` including the stack trace

Comment: @torvin updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in the client library. Try this before doing `AddAsync`:

```
@event.ODataType = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did come across this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420993/could-not-find-member-odata-type-on-object-of-type-teammembersettings and tried adding `ODataType = null` but unfortunately there is no change.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting a new error message about a different type now? Also which version of the client library are you using?

Comment: I added `ODataType = null` to each property, this is the error `he property 'attendees' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event'` it is now an `Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event` this is the same that the Graph Explorer returns. `Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph : 1.8.2`

Comment: Don't you have a reference to `Microsoft.Graph`? Which version?

Comment: oh yes, there is one in the above mentioned package `Microsoft.Graph : 3.27.0`